# Some feed messages return false in graph

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed

I have tried posting to some different friends feeds. Sometimes the message does not show up on feed even if a get a "good" response back with a new graph api ID.

```
100002842168248_146917358746335 does not work for example
```

I don't get any errors or similar only a new ID for the post and when I try to access via graph api (developer console on FB) it return simply false?

https://graph.facebook.com/100002842168248_146917358746335

Using the same call but for another user is showing up on facebook feed without problems. Is there any more action I can take or should I simply take my "false" and give up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a privacy/permission settings issue. If the user who's Wall you are posting too has it set so only Friends can view their Wall, you will not be able to view the post (via the Graph or otherwise) - even though your App *made* the post.

Comment: I'm posting on the behalf of a user (user access token) the posts get published on friends wall but there are set to privacy "Only you" are you able to set the privacy to something other like everyone or friends?

Comment: You *can* set the privacy of a wall post when you make it (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), but I'm not actually sure how that interacts with a user's pre-defined privacy settings. If their Wall is set to "Only Friends" and you post to their wall with the privacy setting "EVERYONE", does it show up for everyone and override the default? You'll have to experiment I guess. "With great privacy controls comes great complexity". ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer this was sure coupled with privacy settings, the user in question had the setting to "Only Me" for "Who can see Wall posts by others on your profile?" setting.

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Note: This privacy setting only applies to posts to the current or specified user's own Wall. Facebook ignores this setting for targeted Wall posts (when the user is writing on the Wall of a friend, Page, event, group connected to the user). Consistent with behavior on Facebook, all targeted posts are viewable by anyone who can see the target's Wall.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Good documentation find!

Answer (score 0):

You can also get 'false' if, although the post is visible on Facebook.com with no problems, the user who posted it has opted out of Facebook Platform. This is a privacy setting which disables any apps from accessing any information about a user, their posts, etc. 
Even if their posts are 'Public' on facebook.com, the API won't return anything about such users.